# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing. B3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

i'm trying to use bootstrap navbar in my project. But it's not working well. Here is the link; http://www.uzuntweet.net/uzuntweet/twitter_api_istek_asimi . How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It would help if you explained your problem? What do you want the navbar to look like?

Comment: if you check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) it's normal navigation bar on browser but when you check it on small size browser or phone it goes responsive mode. I want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the usage of navbar with collapse make sure you have bootstrap3

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OnurŞevik  did the above answer help you, if so can you accept the answer